# Data primary/foreign key relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I would imagine that this will be a simple answer for someone who has developed many database schemas, but I have recently found myself tasked with optimizing (or attempting to optimize rather) a database schema and have been reading through "High Performance MySQL", and am left with a question concerning the use or "over-use" of foreign key relationships within a schema. For example lets say I have the following tables:

```
CUSTOMERS:
__________________________________
|CustIDPK|  Name  |   RegDate    |
----------------------------------
|   1    |  frank |  01-30-2014  |
|   2    |  terry |  02-01-2014  |
|   3    |  amber |  02-02-2014  |
|   4    |  sara  |  02-06-2014  |


PRODUCTS:
____________________________________
| ProdIDPK | ProdName | AddedDate  |
------------------------------------
|    1      |  Phone  | 01-01-2014 |
|    2      |   TV    | 01-02-2014 |
|    3      | Tablet  | 01-02-2014 |
|    4      |   PC    | 01-05-2014 |


PRODUCT_RATINGS:
__________________________________________________________________
| ProdRateIDPK |  ProdIDFK |  CustID |  Rating |    TimeRated    |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1        |     1     |    1    |   8     |   01-01-2014    |
|     2        |     1     |    2    |   7     |   01-01-2014    |
|     3        |     1     |    3    |   8     |   01-02-2014    |
|     4        |     2     |    4    |   6     |   01-02-2014    |
|     5        |     2     |    4    |   6     |   01-03-2014    |
|     6        |     2     |    3    |   4     |   01-01-2014    |
|     7        |     3     |    2    |   5     |   01-02-2014    |
|     8        |     3     |    1    |   7     |   01-03-2014    |
|     9        |     3     |    1    |   4     |   01-04-2014    |
|     10       |     4     |    2    |   9     |   01-04-2014    |
|     11       |     4     |    3    |   8     |   01-01-2014    |
|     12       |     4     |    4    |   7     |   01-01-2014    |
```

The CUSTOMERS table exists independently of the PRODUCTS table therefore no relationship is defined. The PRODUCTS table has a one-to-many relationship with the PRODUCT_RATINGS table since any one product can have many ratings. This much is clear.

Now in the existing schema within the PRODUCT_RATINGS table the column CustID is a foreign key to the CUSTOMERS table, representing a one-to-many relationship with the product ratings since any one user can have many ratings in this table (each rating representing a separate product).

**My question:** Should the 'CustID' column be defined as a foreign key creating a one-to-many relationship with the CUSTOMERS table? I do not see where the need for a join of this data would be necessary. From what I can tell, the 'CustID' column is only used in the application to distinguish which customer issued the rating...

Comment: Note that ProdRateIDPK is rendundant in this schema - on the basis that you have a perfectly adequate PK on (prodid,cust) or (prodid,custid,timerated)

Comment: Any two tables can be joined. The presence of a FK between them just means that the join will have one result row for each referenced table row. Just declare all candidate keys (ie minimal PK/UNIQUE column sets, ie column sets that don't contain smaller ones) & FKs to them. (SQL requires you to declare PK/UNIQUE column sets that are referenced in FKs. So you must also declare those non-minimal PK/UNIQUE column sets and coresponding FKs, which are hence actually foreign superkeys.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with this problem that you mention:   '"over-use" of foreign key relationships within a schema'.  Generally the problem is under-use.

Defining the foreign key relationship does several things.  Most importantly, it guarantees that the `CustId` column in the `PRODUCT_RATING`s table is a valid `CustId` in the `CUSTOMERS` table.  That is very useful.

There are consequences to this, but clarifying that this relationship exists is a part of good schema design.  It is not something to be removed by an unusual notion of "optimization".

Comment: I think the thing that through me for a loop was when they started talking about normalizing and denormalizing for your specific needs and started to think that if a join wasn't happening that the CustID column wouldn't need to be indexed as a foreign key in the PRODUCT_RATINGs table. I understand what you mean about guaranteeing that the CustID is valid. Serious issues could arise if a customer is removed but there is unrelated data still in existence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the CustId field in the product_ratings table should be a foreign key to the customers table.  That is what database normalization is all about.  I didn't read the same book you did, but I have heard good things about Database Design for Mere Mortals.